# Looking for a word that fits for a young grown woodland

Tags: expressions, vocabulary

I'm looking for a word for a young wood of forest. In German you would say "junger Bestand". What ist the english expression - young stand, young stock?

Comment: new-growth forest?

Comment: And if it is a small area with a few trees? Or a reforested area?

Comment: A *"new-growth forest"* is usually a reforested area (although it doesn't have to be). How large an area are you talking about? You could say *"a stand of young trees"* ... I don't think there's a special term in English for anything smaller than a forest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Stand" would be a suitable word in British English. The National Vegetation Classification system uses the so-called "Stand Type system" to classify woodland. See http://jncc.defra.gov.uk/PDF/fieldguidetowoodland.pdf.

"Stand: A group of growing plants of a specified kind, especially trees:" ref http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/stand #6.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this exactly has the nuance you're looking for, as it's forestry-related jargon instead of what a layman might say, but there's a term, "secondary forest" used to describe woodland that is recovering after having been disturbed or burned down.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_forest

Undisturbed forest would be "old-growth forest" or "primary forest": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Old-growth_forest

Answer (score 0):

***young forest*** or ***young stand*** (which OP mentioned)

"What is **young forest**? It’s the shoots and sprouts of young trees springing up again in incredible numbers from the root systems of older trees following a timber harvest. It's an old field thick with shrubs and saplings. It's a tract of swampland choked with emergent shrubs. Young forest can be a pine barrens greening up again following a prescribed burn carried out by a trained fire crew."  from the website of The Young Forest Project [http://youngforest.org/]
[1]

See the "**Young Stand Thinning and Diversity Study** A management study evaluating the ecological, operational, social, and economic consequences of alternative methods of managing 30-50 year-old plantations" from Ecoshare's website.

Concerning Peter Shor's suggestion, I found some photos labeled "New growth forests", which, however, proved to be a mixture of new growth and old growth.

What it isn't, of course, is an old-growth forest (primary, virgin, primeval).  And, according to Wikipedia, second-growth forests refers to well established forests that have grown up after a major disturbance to the earlier growth.   See Wikipedia articles on old growth and secondary growth forests.